# Unix find command having multiple strings in a word

Tags: python, unix

I have many files in a directory like, `"abc_pqr_xyz"`, `"abc_msno_xyz"`........

I'm using find command in unix like

```
find "$PWD"/script/*abc**xyz*
```

but no answer

I had already tried

```
find "$PWD"/script/ * [abc] * [xyz]*
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/index.html), the [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) man page, the [grep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) man page.

Comment: If you want to code in [Python](http://python.org/) be sure to read its documentation. You could be interested in [file and directory access in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html) or in [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). Your question lacks some [mre]

Comment: Probably this unix command will print the requested files in your directory: `ls abc_*_xyz`

Comment: How is your question related to [tag:python]? If you are seeking for help with Unix commands, please use [unix.se] instead of [so].

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find "$PWD"/script/ -name "*abc*xyz*"
```